# How to click on link from array with effect?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hyperlink

I'm trying about effect like "news", where the text will every 5 second fadeOut and next text will show on previous position. But, i have **link** in **arrays** and i cant click on it and select it too. Like the text wouldnt be text and be image or slider.

Here is my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var pages = ["<li class='active'><a id='click' href='http://www.seznam.cz'>link1</a></li>", "<li class='active'><a href='#'>link2</a></li>", "<li class='active'><a href='#'>link3</a></li>"]
  var index = 0;
  setInterval(function() {
    $("#ul_news").html(pages[index]);
    index++;
    if (index >= pages.length){
      index = 0;
    }
    $(".active").delay(4000).fadeOut(1000);
  }, 5000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="ul_news">
</ul>
```

Here it's working, but it doesnt work on my website: [My Website](http://www.thyon.cz)

Can you tell me what is different between this code and code on my website?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not working because there's a `div` overlapping it. (`<div class="Menu">`)

Change the height of `.Menu` to the proper height instead of 768px.

```
.Menu {
    height: 80px;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 18;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your website `<div class="menu">` is overlapping the links , **set the height of .Menu to auto**

```
.Menu {
    height: auto;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 18;
}
```

Comment: Sure! Thank you for you reply. Im losing in my code, because everything is in **position:absolute**